# heapq.merge() function to list of sorted files

Tags: python, sorting, python-2.7

I have a list of sorted files where data is separated by '\n' I want to merge them together to get a single sorted files. I dont want to load content of all the files all at once. I am using **merge function of heapq library**

I wrote the following code

```
def merge(*flist):
    for element in heapq.merge(*flist):
        yield element
```

where *flist is a tuple like this -

```
(<open file '/tmp/000000', mode 'w+b' at 0xb73eba70>,
<open file '/tmp/000001', mode 'w+b' at 0xb73ebac8>, 
<open file '/tmp/000002', mode 'w+b' at 0xb73ebb20>, 
<open file '/tmp/000003', mode 'w+b' at 0xb73ebb78>, 
<open file '/tmp/000004', mode 'w+b' at 0xb73ebc80>)
```

when i printed element above in the loop I am getting value '2\n', '44\n'. The output file is also not in the sorted order. I think the problem is due to new line characters. How to tackle this problem.

I am trying to fix this from quite a long time but couldn't able to resolve it

Comment: Is the data in your input files numerically sorted?

Comment: Are you expecting a sort by ascii-lexicographic order or numerical order? You may need to convert your input elements to integers.

Comment: Please post some sample data and expected output.

Comment: @1_CR yes all the files in tmp are numerically sorted

Comment: @user2357112. I am trying to sort in numerical order

Comment: For strings: `'100' > '2'` is `False`, convert them to integers first.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary -- Thank you for pointing this out. This was the mistake I was making.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert your input lines to integers to get a numeric sort instead of a string sort:

```
def merge(*flist):
    return heapq.merge(*[itertools.imap(int, f) for f in flist])
```

Note that iterating over the `heapq.merge` iterator and yielding every element is pointless. You can just return the iterator and save a layer of indirection. (In fact, the original version of your function could've been replaced with `heapq.merge` without any change to the call sites.)