# merge two sorted files using awk or python

Tags: python, sorting, awk, merge

I have two files depending on only 1st column value.

File 1:

```
2.3 5 3 66
5.5 2 3 54
6.2 4 1 33
```

File 2:

```
1.2 3 7 22
4.5 2 6 77
8.9 4 2 54
```

I want to merge these two files with final sorted file as

```
1.2 3 7 22
2.3 5 3 66
4.5 2 6 77
5.5 2 3 54
6.2 4 1 33
8.9 4 2 54
```

Comment: why not simply `cat file1 file2 | sort`

Comment: @goncalopp I think we are meant to assume that the files are sorted and the asker wants to avoid sorting the merged output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using `sort -m` (merge sorted files):

```
sort -m -n file1 file2 > file3
```

Comment: I did not know that is possible with sort! Sweet! Thanks! See my stupid awk solution below :) I should clearly read the manual for all of the common unix utilities!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a good one, but I think it got down voted, because you didn't provide enough details. If I can assume that the files are already sorted by column 1, that you want the final output to be sorted by column 1 and there are no duplicate values in column 1, then this solution works:

```
cat file1 \
| awk 'BEGIN{
 cmd="cat file2"; cmd | getline line2; split(line2,a," "); key2=a[1]} {
 key1=$1; while(key2<key1) {
   print line2; cmd | getline line2; split(line2,a," "); key2=a[1]};
 print $0} END{
 if(key2>key1) print line2}'
```

You don't need to pipe cat file1 to awk, but I just prefer to have the input file at the beginning of the command instead of at the end. I am often criticised for this redundant use of cat.

Your question is tagged with Python, so here is a Python3 solution as well, which utilises [heapq.merge()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html):

```
import heapq
with open('file1') as fd1, open('file2') as fd2:
    for line in heapq.merge(fd1, fd2):
       print(line, end='')
```

I found the answer, when searching for "merge sorted files in python". Among other pages this one showed up: [heapq.merge() function to list of sorted files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18670466/heapq-merge-function-to-list-of-sorted-files)